# Import a script which imports another script gets ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: import, python-3.7

I am having issues doing a relative import from a imported script.

I have a script structure like so:

```
script1.py
dirname1/
        dirname2/
                 src/
                     script2.py
                     __init__.py
                     util/
                          script3.py
                          __init__.py
```

I am running script 1 from the command line. Like so:

```
python script1.py
```

I have script1 import script 2 like this:

```
import dirname1.dirname2.src.script2
```

When I then try to import script3 from script2 I have issues.

I import that script like this:

```
import util.script3
```

And then I get this module not found error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

I have tried to do

```
import .util.script3
```

however I get a syntax error...

It does work when I import everything relative to the top script. But I would rather be able to import relative to the file which is doing the importing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to place in `dirname1/dirname2/src/util/__init__.py` the following:

```
from .script3 import *
```

Then in `dirname1/dirname2/src/__init__.py` put,

```
from .util import *
from .script2 import *
```

Then you can import all your files in `script1.py` by doing,
import .util

```
from dirname1.dirname2.src import *
```

Then all the commands are accessible

```
commandInScript3()
```

**EDIT**
Or possibly in `script1.py` you can do

```
 from dirname1.dirname2.src import script2,util
 util.commandInScript3()
 script2.cmmandInScript2()
```